# How can I change my location without using fake GPS app?

Tags: gps, geolocation

I am using a fake GPS app on Redmi Note 11 for changing my location, but now the apps are reading that I am using a fake GPS app and they show me a notification like "we are finding a fake GPS app in your phone. Please uninstall them, then you can use the app".

I want to know how can I change my location without using any fake GPS location app or without activating any mock location app in settings?

Comment: Assuming those apps simply scan for the package name of known GPS spoofer apps you could change it's package name: decompile the app using `apktool`, change the package name and the recompile and resign it. As the package name is personally chosen by you the apps can not know it and the GPS spoofer scan should show no results.

Answer (score 0):

Physically move to a different location